# Lambda parameter '<parameter>' hides a variable in an enclosing block

Tags: vb.net, closures

While running the vb.net...coding is working and I got output with below Error...

> Lambda parameter '{parameter}' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.

How can I solve this error?

Here is the code:

Private Sub ButtonProductAdvertisingAPIItemLookup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonProductAdvertisingAPIItemLookup.Click
        sender.Enabled = False

```
    'Product Advertising API, ItemLookup: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html

    Dim ItemId(9) As String

    ItemId(0) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn1.Text)
    ItemId(1) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn2.Text)
    ItemId(2) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn3.Text)
    ItemId(3) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn4.Text)
    ItemId(4) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn5.Text)
    ItemId(5) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn6.Text)
    ItemId(6) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn7.Text)
    ItemId(7) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn8.Text)
    ItemId(8) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn9.Text)
    ItemId(9) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn10.Text)

    ' For Each ItemId As String In ItemIds()

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(ItemIds, Sub(ItemId)

                                                         My.Settings.ItemId = ItemId

                                                         Dim MyREST As New SprightlySoftAWS.REST

                                                         Dim RequestURL(i) As String
                                                         RequestURL(i) = "https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&Version=2011-08-01"
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJCA3UI55HFYAXQ6Q&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Timestamp=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss.fff\Z"))
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&AssociateTag=AKIAJCA3UI55HFYAXQ6Q"
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&ResponseGroup=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString("ItemAttributes,Large,OfferSummary,Offers,VariationSummary,Reviews")
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&ItemId=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ItemId)
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&IdType=ISBN"
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&SearchIndex=Books"

                                                         Dim RequestMethod As String
                                                         RequestMethod = "GET"

                                                         Dim SignatureValue As String
                                                         SignatureValue = MyREST.GetSignatureVersion2Value(RequestURL(i), RequestMethod, "", "8igixqKPKWTcsWxgWdqz+rVofSWIPcC3WynhEl1r")

                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&Signature=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(SignatureValue)

                                                         Dim RetBool As Boolean
                                                         RetBool = MyREST.MakeRequest(RequestURL(i), RequestMethod, Nothing)

                                                         Debug.Print("")
                                                         Debug.Print(MyREST.LogData)
                                                         Debug.Print("")

                                                         Dim Y As Integer
                                                         Dim ResponseMessage As String = ""

                                                         If RetBool = True Then
                                                             Dim MyXmlDocument As System.Xml.XmlDocument
                                                             Dim MyXmlNamespaceManager As System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager
                                                             Dim MyXmlNode As System.Xml.XmlNode
                                                             Dim MyXmlNodeList As System.Xml.XmlNodeList

                                                             MyXmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
                                                             MyXmlDocument.LoadXml(MyREST.ResponseString)

                                                             MyXmlNamespaceManager = New System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(MyXmlDocument.NameTable)
                                                             MyXmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("amz", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")

                                                             MyXmlNodeList = MyXmlDocument.SelectNodes("amz:ItemLookupResponse/amz:Items/amz:Item", MyXmlNamespaceManager)

                                                             If MyXmlNodeList.Count = 0 Then
                                                                 ResponseMessage = "Item not found."
                                                             Else

                                                                 For Each ItemXmlNode As System.Xml.XmlNode In MyXmlNodeList
                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ASIN", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Details of " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf
                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:Title", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Title = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:MediumImage/amz:URL", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Image = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNodeList = ItemXmlNode.SelectNodes("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:Author", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     If IsNothing(MyXmlNodeList) = False Then
                                                                         ResponseMessage += "Author = "
                                                                         For Each MyXmlNode In MyXmlNodeList
                                                                             ResponseMessage += MyXmlNode.InnerText & ", "
                                                                         Next
                                                                     End If

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:ListPrice/amz:FormattedPrice", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "ListPrice = "
                                                                     If IsNothing(MyXmlNode) = False Then
                                                                         ResponseMessage += MyXmlNode.InnerText
                                                                     End If

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:Offers/amz:Offer/amz:OfferAttributes/amz:Condition", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Condition = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:Offers/amz:TotalOffers", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "TotalOffers = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:OfferSummary/amz:TotalNew", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "TotalNew = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNodeList = ItemXmlNode.SelectNodes("amz:OfferSummary/amz:LowestNewPrice/amz:FormattedPrice", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "LowestNewPrice = "
                                                                     Y = 0
                                                                     For Each MyXmlNode In MyXmlNodeList
                                                                         If Y < 25 Then
                                                                             ResponseMessage += "" & MyXmlNode.InnerText & "  "
                                                                         End If
                                                                     Next

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:OfferSummary/amz:TotalUsed", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "TotalUsed = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:OfferSummary/amz:LowestUsedPrice/amz:FormattedPrice", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "LowestUsedPrice = "
                                                                     If IsNothing(MyXmlNode) = False Then
                                                                         ResponseMessage += "" & MyXmlNode.InnerText
                                                                     Else
                                                                         ResponseMessage += "0"
                                                                     End If

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     'MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:SalesRank", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     'ResponseMessage += "SalesRank = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     'ResponseMessage += vbCrLf
                                                                 Next
                                                             End If

                                                             DialogOutput.Text = "Success"
                                                             DialogOutput.TextBoxOutput.Text += vbCrLf & ResponseMessage & vbCrLf


                                                         Else
                                                             ResponseMessage = FormatLogData(MyREST.RequestURL, MyREST.RequestMethod, MyREST.RequestHeaders, MyREST.ResponseStatusCode, MyREST.ResponseStatusDescription, MyREST.ResponseHeaders, MyREST.ResponseStringFormatted, MyREST.ErrorNumber, MyREST.ErrorDescription)

                                                             DialogOutput.Text = "Error"
                                                             DialogOutput.TextBoxOutput.Text = ResponseMessage
                                                             DialogOutput.ShowDialog(Me)
                                                             DialogOutput.Dispose()
                                                         End If

                                                         i = i + 1
                                                     End Sub)
    'Next

    DialogOutput.ShowDialog(Me)
    ClearTextBox(Me)
    sender.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

The error shows in the below line (and the error shows in ItemId variable):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(ItemIds, Sub(ItemId)
```

I have updated extra code..anyone check and help me ?How to solve this problem?Still i got the error..

Comment: Somewhere in the method, you probably already have a variable called `ItemId`.

Comment: when i change the variable name..its shows this error.."value of type '1-dimensional array of string' cannot be converted to 'string'"..           in below lines...My.Settings.ItemId = ItemId  ,and this line  RequestURL(i) += "&ItemId=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ItemId)

Comment: when i change variable name in above 3 lines..its not working..when i execute the file ..its shows "No Source Available"..i cant execute.

Answer (score 0):

Given the errors described, including in the comments:

1. You have `ItemId` declared in the outer routine already.
2. Your `ItemIds` is `IEnumerable(Of String())`, or equivalent.

and some further comments:

- Your excerpt is not complete: you need the closing `End Sub` and `)`.
- You should use `&=`, just like you're already using `&` for concatenation.

Your extra code does not help solve your problem, but it does highlight you need to review much. For example, you're declaring an array of `i+1` `RequestURL` `String`s, then just using the last one of those, and also note these are being executed in parallel so `i` could be almost any value when this actually occurs.

To help solve your problem we'd need the preceding code.

Comment: I closed the End Sub )...Thats not a problem..I got issue from below lines..  

System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(ItemIds, Sub(ItemId)  
My.Settings.ItemId = ItemId     
RequestURL(i) += "&ItemId=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ItemId)

Comment: when i change these lines variables ItemId to some other variable..i got a below error.                                   
"No Source Available.There is no source code available for the current location. Browse to find source."      
                     
How to solve this?I got a result with the error..I want to build program successfully and then will get result.....Please any one help..

Comment: Now i added extra code..please check and tell me how to solve this lambda parameter hides the variable in an enclosing block

Comment: Is `ItemId` a typo, and the array is actually `ItemIds`, or is that really the problem?